# How to refer to environment variables in Cypress config files?

Tags: cypress

I've read [Environment Variables in Cypress](https://www.toolsqa.com/cypress/environment-variables-in-cypress/) and other articles regarding passing environment variables in Cypress runs. However how can I refer to the environment variables in my JSON config files?

For example, I do

```
$ npm run cy:open -- --config-file config/mytests.json --env db.user=db_user,db.password=pw1234abcd
```

because I want to avoid hard-coding the DB creds in my config file, like this

```
{
  ...
  "env" : {
    "db" : {
      "user" : "db_user",
      "password" : "pw1234abcd"
    }
  }
}
```

But what's the syntax in the JSON file to use the passed-in values? What should this look like?

```
{
  ...
  "env" : {
    "db" : {
      "user" : "???syntax???",
      "password" : "???syntax???"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config file is just one source of env variables, the command line is another.

At runtime, they are merged in memory and can be accessed with [Cypress.env](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env.html#Examples).

```js
// cypress.json
{
  "env": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "quux"
  }
}

npm run cy:open -- --env user=db_user

Cypress.env() // => { foo: "bar", baz: "quux", user: "db_user" }
```

In the Cypress runner, click Settings/Configuration to see the merged env object.

---

Passing variables through the command line is a bit limiting, all "nested" type keys (with a '.') are merged in a flat manner, i.e

```js
// cypress.json
{
  "env": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": "quux"
  }
}

npm run cy:open -- --env db.user=db_user,db.password=pw1234abcd

Cypress.env() 
/* => { 
  foo: "bar", 
  baz: "quux", 
  db.user: "db_user", 
  db.password: "pw1234abcd" 
} */
```

But you can apply a reducer to the env object to get a nested structure,

```js
const env = Cypress.env();

Object.keys(env)
  .reduce((env, key) => {
    if (key.includes('.')) {
      const [parent, child] = key.split('.');
      if (!env[parent]) {
        env[parent] = {};
      }
      env[parent][child] = env[key];
      delete env[key];
    }
    return env;
  }, env)

Cypress.env(env); // save back to Cypress if required

console.log(env);

/* => { 
  foo: "bar", 
  baz: "quux", 
  db: {
    user: "db_user", 
    password: "pw1234abcd"
  }
} */
```

Add this at the top of the test, or in **cypress/support/index.js**.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I pass my vars then so they look like `{"db":{"user":"db_user","password":"pw1234abcd"}}` when I look at `Settings->Configuration`? <-- Just like that?

Comment: I tried the way i had it in my previous comment but that syntax didn't work.

Comment: Ok If I do `'{...}'` (enclose in single quote) I the the format I want, but seems like they're not used since I fail by DB connection. I have "other" values in the "db" part of the "env" in my file, I would expect my passed-in vars to be "added" there?