# Combining environment variables in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

This is a follow up to my [How to refer to environment variables in Cypress config files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191104/how-to-refer-to-environment-variables-in-cypress-config-files) post. Steve Zodiac's answer is the correct one indeed.

So I have a config file with environment block like this

```
{
  "env" : {
    ...
    "db" : {
      "user"     : "db_user",
      "password" : "pw1234",
      "host"     : "my_db.company.com",
      "port".    : 3306
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't want to hard code the `user/password` creds so I do this on the command line

```
$ npm run cy:open -- --config-file config/my_config.json --env '{"db":{"user":"db_user","password":"pw1234"}}'
```

and remove the `user` and `password` key/value pairs in my config file.

```
{
  "env" : {
    ...
    "db" : {
      "host"     : "my_db.company.com",
      "port".    : 3306
    }
    ...
}
```

I see the correct `db: user/pw` creds in the Cypress `Setting->Configuration` tab of the Cypress console. However, I see this error when I run above command, that is, as if the DB creds were not correctly set.

```
Error: (conn=716050, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user ''@'10.40.0.44' (using password: NO)
```

If I create a dummy variable, like this

```
{
  "env" : {
    ...
    "db" : {
      "user"     : "dummy",
      "password" : "dummy",
      "host"     : "my_db.company.com",
      "port".    : 3306
    }
    ...
}
```

and run my `npm run cy:open...` command above, I get the following. IOW, the dummy values are not superseded by the passed-in values like I expected.

```
Error: (conn=782727, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user 'dummy'@'10.40.0.44' (using password: YES)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: if you create dummy variables for username and password inside the `cypress.json`, would that help? for eg. inside "db", create something like "user": "dummy", "password": "dummy".

Comment: One problem is `--env` needs a `key=value` format, but you've only given the value part. Even with the proper format, you would not be able to pass an object. The value on the command line is always a string (quoted or not) - that's a limitation of command line env.

Comment: @AlapanDas I updated my OP to answer your question.

Comment: @RichardMatsen, i think i'm giving it the key/value parts, I see them in the Cypress  `Settings->Configuration` console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--env '{"db":{"user":"db_user","password":"pw1234"}}'cyress are you sure its working ?
```

is not valid format are you sure its working ?

when you use -- after run , resst of the commandline options are not passed , try removing the first -- and see you will get parsing error for the

```
--env '{"db":{"user":"db_user","password":"pw1234"}}'
```

the valid format is key:value

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-open-env-lt-env-gt

```
--env db={"user":"db_user","password":"pw1234"}}
```

Once uses JSON.parse() this will be equivalent to

```
"env":{
   "db":{
      {
         "user":"db_user",
         "password":"pw1234"
      }
   }
}
```

So to add the variable to existing variable only way is to update plugin file index.js

```
// cypress/plugins/index.js
module.exports = (on, config) => {


  // modify env var value
  config.env.db.password= config.env.password

  // return config
  return config
}
```

and pass password as

```
 --env  password="something"
```

now you can access this as

```
 Cypress.env('db').password
```

Comment: `--` prceding the options is required because `cy:open` is a script in `package.json`. If the command was `npm run cypress open`, then you would ditch it. See [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script)

Comment: @RichardMatsen cyoress open --env syntax is key:value , not --env {}

Comment: @RichardMatsen thansk richard added

Comment: @RichardMatsen added that sorry i missed it

Comment: Added the answer to the question how to add it to the existing env object

Comment: This did not work. I get `Error: (conn=786273, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user ''@'10.40.0.44' (using password: NO)`

Comment: @ChrisF print the environment variable and see ,

Comment: write a simple code and try , the ndebug your code.

Comment: This worked! the trick was the `module.exports{}` code in `index.js` file